# Django tying subprocesses to logged in user

Tags: django, authentication, subprocess

I have some sub process that may get started while a user is logged in. When the user logs out, I would like to go through all pids associated with the user and kill them.

I am currently using django registration to handle logins.

What should I extend to hold the pids (max of four) to a authenticated users session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set up a model to handle these processes and then have a M2M field in the user profile.

When the user logins in create the model. On logout kill the processes.

**Edit**: Here's possible source.

```
class SubP(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField()

    def run_command(self):
        # runs command
        self.pid = pid_from_command
        self.save()

    def die(self):
        # run kill on self.pid
        ...
```

Comment: do you add a user profile like shown in th eauth topic? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: Django Registration lets you pass in your own User Profile which you add to this.

Answer (score 0):

auth has nice extensibility.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/